# How to configure VS Code to understand nested package.jsons?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, package.json

I have a large React Native application which uses nested `package.json` files to keep the dependency imports at the top of the package clean.

For example, my libraries folder has a `package.json` containing the following:

```
{
  "name": "libraries",
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

This means I can import a tool like so:

```
import { toSnakeCase } from 'libraries/string/transform';
```

the alternative would be

```
import { toSnakeCase } from '../../../libraries/string/transform';
```

This makes the code much simpler to write and reason.

VSCode out of the box does not know how to handle these imports, so a lot of the functionality is missing.

Does anyone know how to correct this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer!
Assuming you're working with Typescript you should have a `tsconfig.json` in your project root.

You need to add the following keys to `tsconfig.json`.

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./src",
  "paths": {
    "constants": ["constants/*"],
    "forms": ["forms/*"],
    "libraries": ["libraries/*"]
  }
}
```

`baseUrl` is essentially the root of your source code.
`paths` is an object detailing where to map the keys to.

Source: https://netbasal.com/sexier-imports-in-typescript-e3c645bdd3c6

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna), which can manage multiple packages together in one folder.

Your repo will become like this, according to the docs:

```
my-lerna-repo/
  package.json
  packages/
    package-1/
      package.json
    package-2/
      package.json
```